# My Scala program does not recognize java.io.File

Tags: scala

Why does not my Scala program recognize `java.io.File`?

```
scala> val in = new java.util.Scanner(java.io.File("~/test.py"))
<console>:13: error: object java.io.File is not a value
       val in = new java.util.Scanner(java.io.File("~/test.py"))
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write code like this `java.io.File("~/test.py")`, it means that you're calling `apply` method of `java.io.File` class. But `File` API doesn't provide such method.

If you want to create a new `File` instance, you should use constuctor:

`new java.io.File("~/test.py")`

Comment: Thanks. Could you pease explain when does "new" is needed, and when it is not, when constructing objects?

Comment: @zell read class API bcz there is no consistency in the question